# Post Doc application during June-July

Tags: job-search, postdocs

Is it possible for a final year PhD student in theoretical high energy physics to apply for postdoctoral positions during June-July if (s)he misses the usual deadlines in Nov-Dec?

(Edited)

Comment: This kind of 'shopping questions' (while useful sometimes) are not usually welcome on this .SE.... check the rules :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the rules. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: @FábioDias Should I delete the post now or wait for a day and then delete? Any suggestion?

Comment: The questions is good if you rewrite it. It should be useful for others grad students in HEP.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Don't know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: @FábioDias that question has absolutely nothing to do with buying anything aka "shoping". The SE specific immensely broad generalization of this term might be useful on the technological sites (?), but it is not appropriate for scientific/academic communities and should therefore not be applied here.  I agree that the question is useful to many students, it should not be closed.